# Material Requirements Planning in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write down a Material Requirements Planning (MRP) using R. My input data consists in:

- Bill of Materials (BOM) composed by the columns of father codes, son codes and utilizatio ratio (but I do not have the level of the BOM)
- Demand for each finished product (each father element of level 0)
- Lead Time for each product

The main issue that I encoutered is related to the fact that many codes could be sons at different levels of the BOM. For instance code B could be son of code A but it could be a son also of code C that is a son itself of code A. Therefore code B results to be a son of both code A and code C, where code C is a son of code A.
Due to this problem, I cannot find a way to generate the total final requirements of materials for this codes (eg code B), as they depend on two different fathers at different levels.

For example:
let's say that we have a dataframe of BOM structured in this way:

```r
BOM<-data.frame(father=c("A","A","B","C","C"),son=c("B","C",NA,"B","D"))
BOM
#   father  son
# 1      A    B
# 2      A    C
# 3      B <NA>
# 4      C    B
# 5      C    D
```

where NA stands for "no sons".

As you can see, whatever is the lead time or the demand (it doesn't matter in this case) code B depends on A at level 1 and on C at level 2. I have to find a way to determine these requirements for all the codes at all the levels.
Do you have some idea?

Thank you!

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: It sounds like you have a directed acylcic graph (DAG), you might want to look into those (theoretically, and then pragmatically within packages such as `igraph`, `ggdag`, or others).